# Posting Stripe metadata to server through Stripe.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am using Stripe.js to make a custom payment form along with NodeJS on the backend, and I was wondering in what way would I send/POST metadata from the client to the server along with the Stripe token etc.

I couldn't really find anything in Stripe docs or Stack Overflow to help me :(

Thanks!

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/api/node#intro ... Everything is here ... What have you tried ?

Comment: @Pogrindis That shows how to add metadata on the server side with the payment, but not how to send it from the client. What I'm trying to do is to use information from a text box on the client, which would then send to the server so that I can use it as metadata.

Comment: So you will need to handle a `POST` request for example on your node server ? Unless I'm missing something.. `Client` -> `NodeJS Server` -> `Stripe` ? Can you demonstrate some of your work so we can see what you are working with ?

Comment: Exactly. But what I'm trying to do is to send it in the same POST request as the Stripe info - is that possible?

Comment: It depends, I have no idea how you are currently `POST`'ing to Stripe.. Would need to see ! Please share! :)

Comment: It's all [here](https://stripe.com/docs/custom-form) and [here](https://stripe.com/docs/charges)

Comment: @EliYazdi: You're building your own form. This means you have a callback in your Javascript code that gets the card token and then add it to your form for example and submits the form to the server. In that case, you simply add extra information to your form along with it. It's not Stripe specific here

Comment: The problem is that it isn't submitting the text fields directly, it sends them to Stripe's servers which then return a token to submit to my server so that the credit card info is secured

Comment: @koopajah oh ok I see what you meant - but what would I put in the callback to do that? (Sorry, I'm new to Node so I might as stupid questions)

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to do it. Apparently it was just me being stupid :) Thanks to both of you for all your help, I really do appreciate that you took your time to help me